# Select a parent's child using index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
:nth-child()
```

- is a selector that is used to select each element that is the nth child of its parent.

Are there any ways to select a parent's child using an index value? I want to get and set each child's properties individually. The structure of my code is:

```
for (var i=0;i<length;i++) {
  //Create a selector that will choose the first child using `index` value
  //Change each child's properties
}
```

I hope someone will help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method, or [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector? And what properties are you wanting to change, exactly; there's likely a better, and easier, way.

Comment: Why not using `each` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$.each()`

simple example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5w5m2/)):
HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr id="test">
         <td>a</td>
         <td>b</td>
         <td>c</td>
         <td>d</td>
         <td>e</td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

jQuery:

```
$.each($("#test").children(), function(index, data){
       alert(index);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#parent').children().length; i++)
 $('#parent').find(":eq("+i+")");
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fMEr8/)

Answer (score 2):

You're over-complicating what you're trying to do, the majority of jQuery methods that allow multiple elements' properties to be changed also allow an anonymous function which iterates over each of those elements, for example to change the text of multiple elements:

```
var colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

// selects the '#container' element's children
$('#container').children()
/* the text method accepts an anonymous function,
   the first parameter is the index of the current element returned by the selectors,
   the second parameter is the 'current' value (so the current text of the element) */
.text(function (i, t) {
    // sets the text to be the current-text + the new string + the index of the element
    return t + ', of index ' + i;
})
// using an object to set multiple CSS properties:
.css({
    // setting the color to the color from the colors array with the same index:
    'color': function (i) {
        return colors[i];
    },
    // increasing the text-indent by 1em for every element
    'text-indent': function (i) {
        return (i * 1) + 'em';
    }
}).filter(function(i){
    /* keeps only those elements whose index, mod 2, is equal to 0
       (so the elements whose index is an even number) */
    return i%2 == 0;
}).css('font-weight', 'bold');;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3gzJY/3/).

The above uses this base HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
    <div>child of "#container"</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).